VMTek Error: The referenced Virtual Machine already has a bundleURL assigned
При скачивали образа из репозитория встроенными в VMTek средствами на последней стадии вылетает ошибка: The referenced Virtual Machine already has a bundleURL assigned.
Подскажите как решить


Обратился в поддержку, ответили что данная проблема связана с обновлением API компанией Apple

MacBook AirM2 macOS Sequoia 15.0
VMTek Version 2.2.5 (225)

Делал следующее (по совету поддержки):

Почистил кеш
Перезагрузил ПК
Отключил VPN

